Wix Heatwave C++ Custom Action Project cannot created
When I create a new project with Visual Studio 2022 I'm getting an error.
I selected the project template "C++ Custom Action Project" for the WIX Heatwave v4.
This is the message I get when I press "Create" button:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041FE1
